# DataStudio Mysql Connection - User Denied

Tags: mysql, database-connection, looker-studio

I created a new user in Mysql, with restricted privileges to do anything with only one VIEW ( GRANT ALL ON mydatabase.myview TO 'myuser'@'localhost'

When I try to connect with this user on DataStudio I got the message 'User denied"   but when I try to connect using any other tool like sequel pro .. the connection is successful.

My question is:   What Privileges are needed to connect with restricted users in DataStudio?   They need to show all databases? show all tables? or any other grant ???

Comment: See this anwser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49545779/304775

Answer (score 0):

By setting 'myuser'@'localhost' you explicitly allow `myuser` to connect only from `localhost` aka your computer.

Google Data Studio operates on the Web, thus does not have access to your local network (see 
https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7088031?hl=en#notes), unlike Sequel Pro which is running locally on your personal computer.

To start with, the correct user to create would be `'myuser'@'%'`